# UNO IllegalArgument during import phase: Source file cannot be read. URL seems to be an unsupported one

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I am trying libreoffice and unoconv to convert xls files to pdf, but so far I am getting "UNO IllegalArgument during import phase: Source file cannot be read. URL seems to be an unsupported one." exception.

- Operating System: RHEL 6
- Unoconv version : 0.5
- Libreoffice version : 3.4.5
- Openoffice :

  - openoffice.org3-writer-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-en-US-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-math-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-draw-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-calc-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-impress-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-base-3.4.1-9593.x86_64
  - openoffice.org3-3.4.1-9593.x86_64

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

It could be when open office don't have read access to your URL or your user don't have execution access to open office.